# Android Facebook app that does not use GPS

Tags: android, gps, facebook, privacy

The official Android app sometimes activates the GPS with no apparent reason.
This is unacceptable. It does not have a setting to disable GPS checks either.

Is there an alternative app that:

- Has a setting to disable GPS, or does not use GPS at all
- Runs on unrooted Android
- Free, ideally open source.

This question is not about Facebook messaging, but rather about wall/newsfeed/events/birthdays, so feel free to post answers that do not have chat features. Apps that include Facebook messaging are OK too, though.

Comment: If by "activate" you mean that it enables it, I don't believe that's true.  I've certainly never had issue with GPS disabled in Settings.

Comment: @MatthewRead: Happened to me at least 10 times. I open the app, immediately the GPS icon appears. Not always reproducible.

Comment: Use the mobile app in a browser?  Doesn't support notifications but otherwise works well enough.

Answer (score 2):

I think [**Atrium**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiantbits.atrium&hl=en) meets your requirements:

- Uses GPS only if you click the "check-in" button
- It can be installed from the play store, on unrooted Android or else.
- It is free, though not open-source.

Besides, it is nice to use; I sometime miss a post or two, but it does the job.

Comment: This software doesn't seem to exist anymore.